# How to create a table view on a view controller when the view controller already inherits from a base view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've got a view controller (TableViewController.swift) which inherits from a base view controller (BaseViewController.swift) like so:-

```
class TableViewController: BaseViewController {
    // Some code
}
```

I want to create a table view on my TableViewController but to do that you have to inherit from UITableViewController but I can't do that because Swift doesn't allow multiple inheritance; is there a way to solve this problem? I am new to Swift.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A tableView is just a **view** underneath, and you can add it in any view controller you desire.

A tableViewController on the other hand is a viewController that comes with a built in tableView.

You **don't need to subclass tableView** only if you want to change its current functionality or appearance.

Just add a table view in your view controller and conform to **UITableViewDataSource** protocol by implementing its required methods (**numberOfSections, numberOfRows and cellForRow**..).

If you need to know when a cell is tapped or other actions on the tableView you should conform to UITableViewDelegate protocol also.

Comment: Glad I could help!